# What is the difference between a Jewish marriage and a Noahide marriage?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, mussar-ethics

Someone said that a Jewish marriage and a Noahide marriage are 2 different things. Could you give some Halakhic support? Ethical differences? I suppose the 2 have different missions, obviously, but could you elaborate please?

Comment: To elaborate on Rambam below: Noahide marriage is a covenant between two equals - both have equal monetary rights and the right to end the marriage. Jewish marriage, on the contrary, is a Kinyan - acquisition of one another, where the wife becomes subordinate to her husband and deprived of many rights and the right to end the relations.

Answer (score 2):

Rambam in [Hilchot Ishut 1:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2853) writes:

> קודם מתן תורה היה אדם פוגע אשה בשוק אם רצה הוא והיא לישא אותה מכניסה לתוך ביתו ובועלה בינו לבין עצמו ותהיה לו לאשה. כיון שנתנה תורה נצטוו ישראל שאם ירצה האיש לישא אשה יקנה אותה תחלה בפני עדים ואח"כ תהיה לו לאשה שנאמר כי יקח איש אשה ובא אליה
>
> Before the Torah was given, when a man would meet a woman in the marketplace and he and she decided to marry, he would bring her home, conduct relations in private and thus make her his wife. Once the Torah was given, the Jews were commanded that when a man desires to marry a woman, he must acquire her as a wife in the presence of witnesses. [Only] after this, does she become his wife. This is [alluded to in Deuteronomy 22:13]: "When a man takes a wife and has relations with her...."
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952874/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-One.htm))

Comment: Does that mean there is no difference between a Noahide marriage between non-Jews and a non-Noahide marriage between non-Jews?